# When do I use parentheses and when do I not?

Tags: javascript

How come I can say:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}
myFunction();
```

Why does the function call in the `setTimeout` not require parentheses, but the last line does?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`myFunction` is a function

`myFunction()` calls the function and yields whatever value the function returns.

The purpose of setTimeout is running code after some time elapses. You need to pass just the function to it (so setTimeout can itself call the function when appropriate) because if you called the function (with the parenthesis) before passing it to setTimeout it would execute *now* instead of after 1 second.

Answer (score 22):

**Nutshell**

- `myFunction` references the function
- `myFunction()` calls the function

**More Words**

`setTimeout` expects a function reference<sup>*</sup> as an argument.

There are circumstances where `setTimeout(myFunction(), 1000)` might make sense, like if `myFunction()` returns a function, e.g.

```
function myFunction() {
    return function() {
        alert("ohai")
    }
}

// Or

const myFunction = () => () => alert("ohai")
```

So:

```
setTimeout(myFunction(), 1000);
```

- `setTimeout` gets the return value of `myFunction`
- `myFunction` returns a function (that calls `alert`)

meaning there will be an alert every second.

See also [Why function statement requires a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086696/438992)

<sup>* *Or a string to be evaluated, but a reference is preferred.*</sup>

Comment: Weird.  JavaScript is a quirky language.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: It is basically the same in Python or C (function pointers). Only providing the name of the function references it. Adding parenthesis behind it calls it. Of course this does not exist in languages where functions are not first class objects and therefore cannot be referenced directly (such as Java).

Comment: It's not that weird :) you can do that sort of thing in C#, VB.NET too. It's a very useful feature.

Answer (score 7):

When you use the parenthesis, it's saying 'call this function now'. So if you say `setTimeout(myFunction(),1000);`, it will use the *return value* of the function as the callback for the timeout. If the return value for the function is not itself a function, you'll get an error because it will try to execute something that isn't executable after the timeout (a string, a number, undefined, etc).

Comment: Although, worth noting: If the string that was returned was something that was executable, like say `alert("Hello world!");` it would work in this context because `setTimeout` can accept strings as js code literals.

Answer (score 2):

In line 2, the function `myFunction` is not called, but passed as an argument to the `setTimeout` function, whereas in line 4 `myFunction` is called; to call a function, you *always* have to use parentheses, even if there are no arguments.

Comment: I think a 25 watt light bulb just went on.

Answer (score 1):

I think this example would make it clearer if i may,

```
function callback() {
  console.log('this function runs on page loads.');
}

setTimeout(callback(), 2000);
```

Here `callback()` function will run immediately after page loads and won't wait 2 seconds.

```
function callback() {
  console.log('this function runs after page loads.');
}

setTimeout(callback, 2000);
```

Here `callback()` function will run after 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The first example is wrong and should never be used.