# can someone please explain what is happening in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I want the browser to display the seconds since it was last refreshed. I don't understand why 
Code 1 does not work;
Code 2 does;
If code 1 does not work why does code 3 work? The `setInterval` call is similar in CODE 1 and CODE 3. The way the function is defined is different. But it is not clear to me why that is making a difference.

Thanks very much for your help. I have just started learning JavaScript.

**CODE 1**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Time Since Refresh</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="timeSinceStart"></span>

<script language="JavaScript">
    var timeRefreshed = new Date();
    function displayTimeSinceStart(){
        var now = new Date();
        //compute elapsed time
        var elapsed = Math.round((now - timeRefreshed)/1000);
        document.getElementById("timeSinceStart").innerHTML = "Time Elapsed: " + elapsed + " seconds."; 
    }

    // Update seconds counter
    setInterval(displayTimeSinceStart(), 1000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CODE 2**
Same as CODE 1, except the `setInterval()` function is written as

```
setInterval("displayTimeSinceStart();", 1000);
```

**CODE 3**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Time Since Refresh</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="timeSinceStart"></span>

<script language="JavaScript">
    var timeRefreshed = new Date();
    var timeSinceStart = {
        displayTimeSinceStart: function(){
            var now = new Date();
            //compute elapsed time
            var elapsed = Math.round((now - timeRefreshed)/1000);
            document.getElementById("timeSinceStart").innerHTML = "Time Elapsed: " + elapsed + " seconds."; 
        }
    }

    // Update seconds counter
    setInterval(timeSinceStart.displayTimeSinceStart, 1000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Code 1* *calls* `displayTimeSinceStart` (because of the `"()"`) instead of passing a reference to it: `setInterval` gets the return value of that function (`undefined`). Drop the parentheses to fix.

*Code 2* passes a string for `setInterval` to evaluate: the parens are required since you want the method to be called when the interval times out.

*Code 3* passes a reference, equivalent to *Code 1* without the `"()"`, so it works.

`setInterval` expects a function reference (preferred), or a string that will be evaluated.

[More details (including why sometimes a method call as a parameter to `setTimeout` makes sense)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not/7969111#7969111).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This and your other post were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In **code 1**, change this line:

```
setInterval(displayTimeSinceStart(), 1000);
```

to this:

```
setInterval(displayTimeSinceStart, 1000);
```

and it should update your time, once a second.  You can see the fixed version work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sL7HN/.

In **code 2**, you are passing a string that will be sent to `eval()` upon each timer tick and that will correctly call the desired function.  This is not a desirable way to code.  Much better to just pass a reference to the function direction and not use a string and `eval()`.

In **code 3**, you are passing a function reference (like my fixed version of code 1) that happens to be a property of an object so the function will be called on each timer tick.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. Appreciate your response.