# Javascript OOP Methods

Tags: javascript, oop

Just wondering, having the following simple code:

```
var object1 = {
    name: function (){
        return 'myName';
    },
    surname: function (){
        return 'mySurname';
    }
};
```

Why does JS returns `function()` in this case object1.name ?

Why does JS returns the expected result `myName` if I call object1.name() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Referencing* `name` returns what `name` *is*–in this case, a function.
2. *Calling* `name` by appending `()`, i.e., `name()`, returns a value–the string `"myName"`.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not/7969111#7969111) to [When do I use parenthesis and when do I not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not) provides more details.

Comment: Thanks, your answer there was complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
object1.name;//Returns the function declaration
object1.name();//Calls the function and returns its value
```

It works like the following code:

```
var myFn = function(){
    return "This is the return value of this function";
}
alert(myFn);//Alerts the myFn function's declaration
alert(myFn());//Alerts "This is the return value of this function"
```

Answer (score 1):

because in `object1.name` you are calling the function declaration

and in `object1.name()` you are calling the function