# no () at end of variable assignment to function

Tags: javascript, function

I don't understand why are there no () after changeName on this line `this.chngName = changeName;` . My logic is that `this.chngName` gets assigned to a function return and the functions have a () at the end. Thanks for answering.

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;

    this.chngName = changeName;

    function changeName(name) {
        this.lastname = name;
    }
}

myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
myMother.chngName("Doe");
document.write(myMother.lastname);
```

Comment: Please don't indent `{`. It's very ugly. Also, your indentation style is not consistent at all. I've re-indented your code in the way it should be.

Comment: Adding the parens *calls* the function: in your case the function will be called *later*, so you only want a *reference* to the function-without parens. See the following for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not/7969111#7969111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they're doing there is referring to the function without calling it.

```
var x = foo;   // Assign the function foo to x
var y = foo(); // Call foo and assign its *return value* to y
```

In JavaScript, functions are objects. Proper objects. And so you can pass references to them around.

for more clarification : [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Comment: To make it clearer, you could say that y = x(); is the same as y = foo();

Answer (score 1):

The function is assigned, not called. Otherwise `myMother.chngName("Doe");` couldn't work since the function does not return another function. Assigning the return value of `changeName()` wouldn't make sense anyway, since it doesn't return anything (so it automatically returns `undefined`).

More detailed description: Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript. This means (besides some other things) that they can be passed around like any other value/object and assigned to any variable. In this case the function `changeName` which is local to the scope of the `person` constructor function is assigned to the object, making it available from outside (actually, from any place where the object created by `new person()` is available).