# Why does custom function says invalid argument in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have this custom js function

```
$.fn.sense=function func() {
```

and I am calling it later as

```
setTimeout($.fn.sense(),1);
```

Now the above line is giving a weird error on **IE8** .. It says invalid argument? :(

How so? It works in all sane browsers

Comment: take the `()` off `sense`, you are calling the function instead of passing the function

Comment: Awesome please put this as anwer..Solved!

Comment: Does your function return a function? If not, stop calling it, and pass only the reference. See e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/7969111/438992.

Comment: Why would you put a function that can be `setTimeout`'d on `$.fn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
setTimeout($.fn.sense,1);
```