# Function is being called without trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I want to use in order to expand menus in various places. I expect it to be triggered on a click of menu associated button, but at the moment it is being called on page load (I assume from within document ready), and class 'expanded' is added without clicking on a buton. I am confused to why this happens, as it should be called `.on('click' ..`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#btn-expand-mobile-nav').on('click', showMenu('#side-navigation'));

});

function showMenu(menu) {
    var x = $(menu),
        y = 'expanded';
    if (x.hasClass(y))
        x.removeClass(y);
    else
        x.addClass(y);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but consider using `toggleClass`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7969111/438992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the function immediately. Instead defer the execution using an anonymous function:

```
$('#btn-expand-mobile-nav').on('click', function(){
     showMenu('#side-navigation')
});
```

*If* there were no parameters you *could* have done this:

```
$('#btn-expand-mobile-nav').on('click', showMenu);
```

Simplistic explanation for `@skobaljic`:

By using the function name alone, you are pointing at the variable `showMenu` and saying call this later as a function.

By using `function(){}` you are saying, here is a temp variable, containing a function, that you can call later.

e.g. it is the same as:

```
var temp = function(){
     showMenu('#side-navigation')
}
$('#btn-expand-mobile-nav').on('click', temp);  // No parenthesis on temp
```

As `@Dave Newton` rightly points out, this can be simplified using `toggleClass`:

```
$('#btn-expand-mobile-nav').on('click', function(){
     $('#side-navigation').toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

Comment: This is interesting, why the function without parameters is not called, but the one with parameters is?

Comment: @skobaljic: The one without parameters has no `()`

Comment: Would `$('#btn-expand-mobile-nav').on('click', showMenu.bind(this, '$side-navigation'));` work?

Comment: Yes, but why? The explanation would fit well in your answer, would like to see it.

Comment: @Andy: That's a horrible alternative :)

Comment: @skobaljic: Added simplest explanation I could come up with for you :)

Comment: @skobaljic A function reference without parentheses is just the reference, no call. Adding the parens is what turns it from a plain reference into a call. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7969111/438992

Comment: Heh, you like to answer me :) Just wanted [TrueBlueAussie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/201078/trueblueaussie) to improve the answer.