# Javascript iterate through class onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to iterate through a class and display the corresponding text when I hover over each element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box red"></div>

<div class="box green"></div>

<div class="box red"></div>

<div class="info">
Hi
</div>

<div class="info">
Hello
</div>

<div class="info">
Hey
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}

.info {
  display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].onmouseover = function(){
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
    info[i].style.display= "block";
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
box[i].onmouseout = function(){
  var info = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
  info[i].style.display= "block";
  }
}
```

I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"
```

It works if I set each `<div>` with an `<id>` then repeat my code over and over again. Why is it not working if I iterate?

https://jsfiddle.net/4q8jrt2m/2/

Comment: Each loop, `i` gain `1`. At the end of the third loop, `i` gain `1` so `i = 3`. Because of it, the code inside the loop are not executed avec the third. But it's to late, because when onmouseover is executed, i don't change or reset, so `i = 3` and that's why `info[i]` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var info = document.getElementsByClassName("info")
for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
box[i].onmouseover = show(i);
box[i].onmouseout = hide(i);
}



function show(index){
return ()=>{info[index].style.display='block'
}}

function hide(index){
return ()=>{info[index].style.display='none'
}}
```

Comment: How does this line work? 
```return ()=>{info[index].style.display='none'
}}``` 

Why can't I just write 

```function hide(index){
info[index].style.display='none';
}```

Comment: because we passed parameters with it, which would fire the function immediately without onmouseover event for example getting triggered. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29965761/14283533 
to solve this we warp it into another function

Answer (score 0):

A perfect candidate for [event delagation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) I'd say. Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", handle); 

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("box")) {
    const hoveredColor = [...evt.target.classList][1];
    const info = document.querySelector(".info");
    info.dataset.hovered = hoveredColor;
    info.style.color = hoveredColor;
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}

.info {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  left: 150px;
  top: 1rem;
}

.info:after {
  content: attr(data-hovered);
}
```

```html
<div class="box red"></div>

<div class="box green"></div>

<div class="info"></div>
```