# Different usage of parentheses between html inline events handler and unobtrusive event handler

Tags: javascript

When I want to execute a script myFunction(){} when a page is loaded I have two choices.

```
1 <body onload="myFunction()">
2 <script> window.onload = myFunction </script>
```

My question is why we need parentheses in the first case but not in the second case? What is the theory behind it?

Comment: In one you're calling it (with the parens), in the other you're setting a reference to it (without the parens), e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/7969111/438992

Comment: The browser is firing whatever function you are assigning to the `onload` property for you. (Hooking)

Comment: @HaNdTriX You do if you want the function to run on load.

Comment: @HaNdTriX ... That has parens. Did you mean quotes? IMO you should use the quotes for clarity anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute version dates back to the early days of Javascript and is not advanced enough to support the notion of referencing a function rather than stating a script fragment to evaluate.  Its usage is frowned on nowadays by those who advocate modern Javascript techniques.

Comment: Since this is a multiple SO dupe let's find and point to those instead of posting identical answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

is a function call: when the page is loaded, the function is called.

```
<script> window.onload = myFunction </script>
```

is a reference to the function object. It is a better solution, if only because inline javascript is irritating to read, with its mix of HTML and javascript, while scripts can be separately written and managed.

Comment: Since this is a multiple SO dupe let's find and point to those instead of posting identical answers.