# JavaScript not waiting on promise to resolve

Tags: javascript

In the following code, what I'm after is to get the alert, after the counting is finished in the setInterval.  The alert shows first though, and then the counting happens.  What have I done wrong?

```js
function function1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('in function1 ')
    function2().then(resolve());
  });
}

function function2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var x = 0;
    I = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(x);
      if (x > 10) {
        clearInterval(I);
        resolve()
      };
      x++
    }, 100);
  });
}

function1().then(alert('finished'));
```

Comment: The argument to `.then()` must be a function, not a call of the function. `.then(() => alert('finished'))`

Comment: @Barmar don't forget `function2().then(resolve());`, which is broken in a similar fashion.

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)

Comment: Right, that can just be `.then(resolve)`

Comment: Thank you all.  It was the function call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I use parenthesis and when do I not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969088/when-do-i-use-parenthesis-and-when-do-i-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)'s first argument:

> **onFulfilled** : A Function called if the Promise is fulfilled. This function has one argument, the fulfillment value. If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an "Identity" function (it returns the received argument).

You can either pass a function name or a function as below:

```js
function function1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('in function1 ')
    function2().then(resolve); // onFulfilled
  });
}

function function2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var x = 0;
    I = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(x);
      if (x > 10) {
        clearInterval(I);
        resolve()
      };
      x++
    }, 100);
  });
}

function1().then(() => alert('finished')); // onFulfilled
```