# NodeJS is not running imported function

Tags: node.js

I have an `index.js` where I import a module:

```
const msg = require('../server/email/sendMail');

console.log(msg);
```

In my `sendMail` file I have:

```
// sendMail.js

function main() {
  return 'message'
}

module.exports = {main};
```

When I run the index.js file I get:

> { main: [Function: main] }

I expected the string `message` to be shown in the log.

Comment: It's *you* who is not calling the function. Node doesn't randomly execute variables as functions without being told to. Either do `console.log(msg())` or export the result of calling the function. I don't know which one you want here.

Comment: *"I expected the string message to be shown in the log."* - Why?  Where do you execute your `main()` function?  The function is defined, and imported, but where specifically is it executed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7969088/438992

Comment: @PeterBoomsma It’s a pretty reasonable question—you’re calling other functions (`require` and `log`) but not the one you’re asking about—understanding why the expectation was there is often helpful when explaining.

Answer (score 1):

To run a function you need to add `()` at the end of the function name:

```
msg()
```

So you need to do:

console.log(msg())

On the other hand, to pass the **function** around as a variable (not run it) instead of the *result* of the function you don't add the `()`:

```
let a = msg
let b = msg()

// a is now the function
// b is the string "message"

console.log(a()) // prints 'message'
```

Comment: Wauw. How did I not see that...